# How do I use an older version of Outlook beyond what is supported?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Whenever I open Outlook 2010 to access my outlook.com account (not provided by school oro work), a messagebox appears, saying, "blocked the version of outlook that you are using".  Is there a way around this?  Can I change the version that is sent to the server without upgrading, like sending a custom user-agent?

Comment: If they're going to the effort of actively blocking a given version, it's probable that it's because it won't work. Office 2010 went End of Life two years ago.

Comment: Outlook generally supports most email systems. Why not upgrade Outlook (Office)?

Comment: It probably is blocked because it doesn’t support newer security features

Comment: @John that's not in the budget right now.

Comment: tbh, you've had seven years to save up. It went unsupported in 2015 & totally EoL two years ago. Heva a look at the free online version of office - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/free-office-online-for-the-web

Comment: It still came as a surprise.  I would still prefer to not update office and save money.  I'm not a fan of planned or forced obsolescence.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *free* email client such as [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/), which works well [with Outlook.com](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-hotmail). Some additional advantages are being able to connect to *multiple* email accounts (e.g., Gmail and Mail.com) and usability on other OS platforms, such as Mac and Linux, as well as on MS Windows.

Comment: I have Thunderbird.  I like the similarity to Firefox and being able to install it with choco, but I prefer Outlook overall as an email client.